# Finding the determinant of $2A+A^{-1}-I$ given the eigenvalues of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A$ be a $2\times 2$ matrix whose eigenvalues are $1$ and $-1$. Find the determinant of $S=2A+A^{-1}-I$.

Here I don't know how to find $A$ if eigenvectors are not given. If eigenvectors are given, then I can find using $A=PDP^{-1}$. Please solve for $A$; the rest I can do.

Comment: `eigenvalue` and `eigenvector` are single words (there's no space after `eigen`). [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for how to typeset common math expressions with LaTeX, and [see here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to use Markdown formatting. [Here is how I edited your question](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/27b535c3-7e96-4e44-a693-a3cdb863eb94/view-source).

Comment: Your post's title and the question in the body of the post don't necessarily match...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

If $A=PDP^{-1}$ then  $S=P(2D+D^{-1}-I)P^{-1}$.

Comment: That should be $2D$ as first summand?

Comment: then what will be P if eigenvectors are not given

Comment: @DavidJones We don't need the eigenvectors to be given.  $\det( PDP^{-1} ) = \det(D)$.

Comment: @ Hagen von Eitzen Yes, thank you. I will correct

Comment: @ David Jones: Your question was answered by Andrew Salmon.

Answer (score 1):

If $u,v$ are eigenvectors of $A$ for the eigenvalues $1,-1$ respectively then $Su=(2A+A^{-1}-I)u=2Au+A^{-1}u-u=2u+u-u=2u$. Similarly $Sv=-4v$. Therefore the eigenvalues of $S$ are $2,-4\ldots$

Comment: A good answer using only basic ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Take the Jordan form and all it's easy:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&\!\!-1\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{pmatrix}
0 &-1 \\ 
 -1&0 
\end{pmatrix}

the Characteristic polynomial is $(x-1)(x+1)$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! You should be aware that this site supports [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/), which allows users to format mathematical expressions using $\LaTeX$.  Please peruse [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for an introduction to formatting mathematical expressions here, and consider editing your post use this functionality.  (Others will appreciate your efforts!)

Comment: As an additional comment, though the (original) title of the question makes it appear that an example of a matrix given given eigenvalues is desired, the body of the question makes it clear that something else is asked for.

Comment: hello, but how do i use mathjax ? do i need to download something ?

Comment: No, you don't need to download anything.  It is a JavaScript library that runs automatically (on modern browsers).  Your post should now be displaying properly, thanks to the efforts of learner.  Click on the [edit](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/401833/edit) button to see how the markup has been changed to make this all happen.